# Is there a way to disable Google Analytics tracking in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics, phantomjs

I want to track some sites using PhantomJS, but I don’t want to spam peoples Google Analytics. Is there a way to disable the Google Analytics tracking script (ga.js / analytics.js) from sending data to Google? Like it is possible with the usual GAOptOut browser plugins.

I had a look in the Chrome Plugin and tried the code from that, but it doesn’t seem to be executed when telling PhantomJS to do so (onLoadStart).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `page.onResourceRequested` method to abort all requests to google analytics.

```
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request) {
    if ((/google-analytics\.com/gi).test(requestData['url'])){
        console.log('Request to GA. Aborting: ' + requestData['url']);
        request.abort();
    }
};
```

Related, full example: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/loadurlwithoutcss.js

Comment: The answer is not wrong, but you should avoid blocking the requests in the first place, and instead return data that reflect what is typically used by those endpoints. In case of Google Analytics, that would mean responding with 204 response. Here is a code example of that: ray.run/blog/blocking-google-analytics-in-playwright-tests

Answer (score 0):

I've just done some testing with Googles Analytics Real Time view. The "Filter Bots" option appears to filter out PhantomJS.

I'm using PhantomJS as part of BackStopJS - but I believe they're using a stock PhantomJS too.

Before hacking on work-arounds like I was about to - check to see whether you're filtered anyway.

Another solution I came across, if that doesn't work for you, was to block google-analytics on your testing machine with:

```
127.0.0.1    www.google-analytics.com
127.0.0.1    google-analytics.com
```