# Is there a way to block requests to the most common trackers using phantomJS?

Tags: phantomjs, screen-scraping

Using Fiddler, I am monitoring all network traffic during phantomJS-based scraping. 
I discover that http://www.venez.net/tracker.js?site_id=4&section_id=0 gets called once for every session on port 9524.

**What is the purpose of this call?**

**Edit:**

As suggested below, this may be because the scraped site calls this tracker. **Is there a way to block requests to the most common trackers using phantomJS, maybe involving a dict of some kind?**

**Edit 2**:

It has been suggested that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274112/is-there-a-way-to-disable-google-analytics-tracking-in-phantomjs) provides a solution. However, this is not the case AT ALL since I am also blocking google analytics and as we can see, the aforementioned tracker still gets called. None of the code in this solution has any relation to things different than google analytics.

[image: venez.net].

Comment: `phantomjs:9524` appears to refer to line 9524 in the phantomjs source file. Look at that line and see what it does. Additionally, take note of whether the site that you're scraping might be responsible--it's very likely that the site itself refers to a venez dot net tracker.

Comment: is there a list of most common trackers and some way to block them directly with phantomJS rather than with Fiddler?

Comment: I would have not the faintest idea. Feel free to edit your updated inquiry into your post that it is more visible to others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to disable Google Analytics tracking in PhantomJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274112/is-there-a-way-to-disable-google-analytics-tracking-in-phantomjs)

Comment: not really. I have blocked google analytics using the solution from the link you provided - however, I still see vendez dot net